# Sistema de Conquistas/Proezas em PHP

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de conquistas/proezas/insígnias em PHP.

A aplicação será para um jogo no qual usa uma base de dados SQL Server e arquivos do servidor em um Cloud, porém não tenho como fazer alterações no jogo de modo que seja atualizado em tempo real.

Se eu colocasse para atualizar em CronJob e houvesse mais de 30,000 usuários na base de dados, ficaria viável?

Um exemplo do que estou a desenvolver: [steamcommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/id/EdHuufeland/badges/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é muito relativo e vai depender do fluxo de utilizadores e das tabelas envolvidas.

Se não há maneira de modificar o script do jogo para que grave os dados a medida em que o utilizador avançar, então só vejo o cronjob como solução.

Você tem que analisar o seguinte:

- Qual o período ideal para executar o cronjob, ou seja, com menor fluxo de utilizadores?
- Se o fluxo é grande a todo tempo, o seu servidor aguenta todo o processamento?
- O seu script que actualiza o banco de dados, consome muita memória?

Com a reposta em mãos, você irá saber:

- Se a sua arquitectura é a melhor escolha. Talvez seja uma exagero, mas não seria melhor passar para um banco de dados distribuído;
- Se o seu servidor precisa de um upgrade e se essa solução basta;
- Se o seu script (que actualiza o banco de dados) precisar ser optimizado;
- Se o banco de dados precisa ser optimizado.

Como pode ver, se não quer afectar a performance da aplicação, terá que ter alguns cuidados e não simplesmente fazer um cron job, mas isso só você que conhece o sistema poderá responder.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Filipe, eu estava pensando, já que uso o SQL Server, eu poderia deixar essas atividades para os procedimentos da base de dados usada, concorda? Acho que o uso seria menor.

Comment: @EdgardHufelande eu não tenho certeza, mas sempre que executo um update na base de dados é sempre mais rápido que no próprio php, por isso penso que sim, um schedule no banco seria mais rápido.